# PHP confirmation email not working because of "\" in link

Tags: php, html, validation, email, confirmation

when sending a confirmation email the confirmation code looks like this `http://mydomain.com\/confirmreg.php?code=3f76ab3a202e73fb0526cd2091c5b7ce` (randomly generated) how do i remove the "\" before the /confirmreg.php

heres some of the code for the link

```
$confirm_url = $this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder().'confirmreg.php?code='.$confirmcode;
```

Comment: Disable magic quotes.

Comment: What's `$this`? You'll need to give us the code that generates the "Absolute URL Folder"

Answer (score 1):

```
$domain = rtrim($this->GetAbsoluteURLFolder(), "\\/");
$confirm_url = $domain .'/confirmreg.php?code='.$confirmcode;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stripslashes($confirm_url)` to get rid of the backslash, but I don't know how `GetAbsoluteURLFolder()` works so the problem may be in there, or something to do with magic quotes.